# Unable to get data from Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, replication, spring-data, couchbase

I'am working on **Couchbase** and **Elasticsearch** with **spring data**. I have a **replication** that is started from Couchbase to Elasticsearch. Now I can save data in couchbase using spring data, data is saved properly and gets replicated into Elasticsearch. While trying to read from Elasticsearch it shows null, only id values show in the result. When I save directly in Elasticsearch it's possible to read correctly. I guess it's because of structural change with data. How can I solve this?

Data in Elasticsearch after replication:

```
{

"_index": "streams",
"_type": "couchbaseDocument",
"_id": "e8c7999c-67c8-47a4-b235-726d89102f83",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
    "meta": {
        "id": "e8c7999c-67c8-47a4-b235-726d89102f83",
        "rev": "3-000007c43e1293830000000000000000",
        "expiration": 0,
        "flags": 0
    },
    "doc": {
        "createdOn": "20141201183646786",
        "activityId": "c3c0dc11-16b5-479b-80c5-93d2ce34d77d",
        "_class": "com.netspective.streams.model.Activity",
        "documentType": "Activity",
        "objectId": "UserAgent_1",
        "subjectId": "{"actionId":"111"}",
        "actionId": "2",
        "updatedOn": "20141201183646786",
        "deleteStatus": false
    }
}

}
```

Data in Elasticsearch that is inserted directly:

```
{

"_index": "streams",
"_type": "couchbaseDocument",
"_id": "45ebb326-a33e-43f2-9fd7-60953cb14772",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
    "id": "45ebb326-a33e-43f2-9fd7-60953cb14772",
    "activityId": "56d291bc-eacd-4942-b26d-08025eec0ab1",
    "subjectId": "{"actionId":"123"}",
    "objectId": "UserAgent_1",
    "documentType": "Activity",
    "createdOn": "20141202113523979",
    "updatedOn": "20141202113523979",
    "deleteStstus": false,
    "action": "2"
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to update the Elasticsearch mappings if you have changed the structure of your data.

Take a look at the [Indexing Issues](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/elastic/trbl-indexing.html) section of the [Elasticsearch plugin documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/elastic/intro-elasticsearch.html), which describes how to address this.

Comment: is it possible to remove doc and meta field? In template it allow only to tell fields that need to replicate, I think it not allow to change the structure. Is it?